# Differences between points and lines as poles in an equal area projection

Tags: coordinate-system

I am planning on using an equal area projection in a current project. I used [this website](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~savricb/selectiontool/) to determine which projection I should be using.

I hadn't previously considered it, and was wondering if there are any hard set guidelines/rules about the advantages or disadvantages of poles being represented as points or lines (I will eventually be calculating total values of rasters throughout the globe).